# POSTMAN - Schema validation is passed even for bad response data

Tags: json, validation, schema, postman

tests["Valid schema"] = tv4.validate(jsonData, schema); is passed even if "error" and "responseType" is missing in the schema. How to make sure that response and schema both are matching for JSON schema.

when I hit post request on postman, the following is the Response Body in postman

```
{  
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Email/Phone number not found",
  "responseType": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",
  "arabicMessage": "البريد الإلكتروني / رقم الهاتف غير موجود"
  }
```

Tests in Postman

```
var jsonData=JSON.parse(responseBody)
var schema ={
    "statusCode": {"type":"integer"},
    "message": {"type":"string"},
    "arabicMessage":{"type":"string"},
    "data": {
        "accessToken": {"type":"string"},
        "userDetails": {
            "_id": {"type":"string"},
            "deviceType": {"type":"string"},
            "countryCode": {"type":"string"},
            "OTPCode": {"type":"integer"},
            "invitationCode": {"type":"string"},
            "availableCredits": {"type":"integer"},
            "totalBookings": {"type":"integer"},
            "promoCodes": {"type":"array"},
            "updatedAt": {"type":"string"},
            "createdAt": {"type":"string"},
            "language": {"type":"string"},
            "IsDeleted": {"type":"boolean"},
            "IsVerified": {"type":"boolean"},
            "IsBlock": {"type":"boolean"},
            "customerAddresses": {"type":"array"},
            "address":{"type":"string"},
            "phoneVerified": {"type":"boolean"},
            "currentLocation": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                   {"type":"integer"},
                   {"type":"integer"}
                ]
            },
            "appVersion": {"type":"integer"},
            "profilePicURL": {
                "thumbnail": {"type":"string"},
                "original": {"type":"string"}
            },
            "password":  {"type":"string"},
            "socialId": {"type":"string"},
            "phoneNo": {"type":"integer"},
            "email": {"type":"string"},
            "LastName": {"type":"string"},
            "firstName": {"type":"string"},
            "__v": {"type":"integer"},
            "referralCode":  {"type":"string"},
            "accessToken": {"type":"string"},
            "deviceToken":  {"type":"string"}
        },
        "updateAvailable": {"type":"boolean"},
        "stateCallBookingIds":  {"type":"array"},
        "forceUpdate": {"type":"boolean"}
    }
 };
tests["Valid schema"] = tv4.validate(jsonData, schema);
//here the test is passing even with invalid jsonData which is the data                       
 console.log("Validation failed: ", tv4.error);
```

Comment: Could you post an image of the Postman output so that we can see what it's validating against?

Comment: FYI the response body which I mentioned above itself is the postman output @DannyDainton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of [open issues](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3173) on the Postman github account about the `tv4` module.

There is a similar question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250036/postman-returns-fail-for-schema-validation-test?rq=1), could your `jsonData` be different than your schema?

This is an [example](http://json-schema.org/examples.html) from a link on the tv4 github page.

```
"title": "Person",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "firstName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "age": {
        "description": "Age in years",
        "type": "integer",
        "minimum": 0
    }
},
"required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
}
```

You could try adding those fields as `required`?

Comment: thanks, I have tried again using "properties " and" required". it is working now.

Comment: @RanjithKasu Cool, did that answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Just leaving this here in case it helps anyone else. `tv4.validate` has two additional boolean parameters: `checkRecursive` and `banUnkownProperties`.

Especially the last one can help finding errors in JSON responses when they contain attributes that weren't defined in the schema.

[Reference](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4#the-banunknownproperties-flag)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use jsonSchema this way:

```
var strSchema = 
pm.collectionVariables.get("variable_that_contains_the_schema");

pm.test("Validate SCHEMA is OK", () => {
    pm.response.to.have.jsonSchema(JSON.parse(strSchema));
});
```

And if you want to auto-generate the schema, you can use the generate-schema plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-schema

I use to store the content of this plugin in a collection variable, on the pre-request of my collection, like this:

[image: pre-request configs]

Then in the test tab of your request, you can call the javascript eval() to load the generate-schema source-code in the postman's test environment:

```
// eval will evaluate the JavaScript generateSchema code and 
// initialize the js on postman environment
eval(pm.collectionVariables.get("generate-schema"));

var strSchema = 
pm.collectionVariables.get("variable_that_contains_the_schema");

if (strSchema === undefined){
  console.log('>>>> variable for schema not defined!');
  return;  
}
if(strSchema == '' | strSchema === null) {
    // call function generateSchema (external)
    var schema = generateSchema.json("variable_that_contains_the_schema", jsonData);

    delete schema.$schema; // remove the element '$schema' --> causes error in validator
    var strSchema = JSON.stringify(schema);

    //save the generated schema
    pm.collectionVariables.set("variable_that_contains_the_schema", strSchema);
    console.log(" >> schema was generated from the response, validation will proceed on the next request.");
}
else
{
    console.log(" >> schema recovered from variable.");

    // Schema test ------------------------------------------------
    pm.test("Validate SCHEMA is OK", () => {
        pm.response.to.have.jsonSchema(JSON.parse(strSchema));
    });
}
```