# How do I test JSON schema in postman using tv4?

Tags: postman, tv4

This is what i am trying, but it always passes the test even for bad results.

```
pm.test("Schema is valid", function () {
    var data = pm.response.json();
    var schema = {
        ...
        my schema
        ...
    };
    tv4.validate(data, schema);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POSTMAN - Schema validation is passed even for bad response data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48012722/postman-schema-validation-is-passed-even-for-bad-response-data)

Answer (score 12):

The reason this doesn't work is (in short) that the underlying library used by Postman (tv4) is no longer maintained. Having come across the problem earlier today, I found a [solution](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3173#issuecomment-347634583):

```
tv4.validate(data, schema, false, true)
```

The latter two parameters are checkRecursive and [banUnknownProperties](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4#the-banunknownproperties-flag). Setting these two flags as shown above make the validation work as expected.

You may also find this code snippet useful, which reports any validation errors via the console:

```
pm.test("Response body is valid", function() {
  var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
  var valid = tv4.validate(data, schema, false, true);
  if (valid !== true) {
      console.log(tv4.error);
  }
  pm.expect(valid).to.be.true;
});
```

Comment: I`m not able to comment yet to comment on @Justin Finkelstein answer, so : The answer he provide and all other related articles answers does not work. It will still return true. Even if your schema is : ```
var schema = "dummy text, not real schema " ```
it will still say that your schema is valid
I`m tired looking for solution. Spend whole 12 hours